# Why does this selector return two elements on this page in Chrome?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Pretty straightforward. I think I have what should be a unique selector, but in Chrome it returns two `<p>` elements. The page I'm looking at is:

```
http://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/control_panel.html
```

and the selector is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body:nth-child(2) div#container:nth-child(1) div#content.clear.hasCorners:nth-child(2) div.document:nth-child(3) div.documentwrapper:nth-child(1) div.bodywrapper:nth-child(1)  div.body:nth-child(1) div#the-control-panel.section:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(3)')
```

I must be misunderstanding something about the `nth-child` selector because I would think this is guaranteed to be unique.

**EDIT:** Ah, I should definitely be using some child selectors (`>`) here to avoid going further down the DOM tree. Someone can feel free to answer it with that and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, the issue is that without the child selector (`>`) there's no guarantee of uniqueness because there may be additional matches further down the DOM tree. For instance consider this markup:

```
<body>
  <div class="foo" id="bar">
    <div class="foo" id="baz"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

if you tried:

```
$('body:nth-child(1) .foo:nth-child(1)')
```

that would return two elements.

Comment: A note for future readers. A common pitfal is that `:nth-child(xxx)` is not properly understood. `body:nth-child(1)` selects the `<body>` element which is a **first child**, with respect to the parent (container). Note that this index is one-based. Also note (repeat) that it does *not* select the first ever `<body>` element, but a `<body>` element which happens to be the *first* child.